# Adding UIButton Programmatically won't show

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios8

I'm currently making an `iOS 8 application` ready for the app store upon iOS 8 release, I don't obviously **I cannot show much code as I'm keeping the project very quiet** but I am creating a view controller with a scroll view and many objects throughout to create a profile for the user, however I'm trying to add a button to all the user to add projects to their profile and the button won't get added to the scroll view... Is there an unwritten rule with `UIButton`s and `UIScrollView`s?

Heres the code I'm using to create the button

```
UIButton *addProject = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18)];
[addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(addProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scrollView addSubview:addProject];
```

Is there something I need to do differently to add it to the scroll view?

**EDIT 1:** `_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 699);`

**EDIT 2:** Also, the scroll view is created in the storyboard and has a frame of `0, 64, 320, 455` but the content size as above has a larger height

Comment: can you show your scrollView frame ?

Comment: Just added the content size is that what you were after?

Comment: How did you added the scrollView using storyboard or programmatically

Comment: Just added that edit in as well haha using storyboard

Comment: try with code posted in my answer

Comment: Just edited your answer, to what is working changed the UIButtonType from custom to roundedrect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this;

```
UIButton *addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addProject.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18);
[addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(addProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scrollView addSubview:addProject];
```

Try to add this line;

```
addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It's some time happens that it may not appear due to same background color.

Comment: Still nothing... Any other ideas?

Comment: Now that works, how do I make the value a + like it would be in the bar rather than just setting the title to @"+" which is a small +

Comment: UIButtonTypeCustom doesn't work... UIButtonTypeRoundedRect does

Comment: I have used the above code to create a UIButton. When we click the button multiple times the action will not happen. This is intermittent what could be the reason for this.

Comment: @Raghav Please make sure the user interaction is enable for your super view and your button.

Comment: Yes, the user interaction is enabled, we have navigation controller, on click it will take to next screen and on clicking the back button it will come back to main screen. If i repeat the above steps multiple times then at some moment it will nt work and instantly on next click it will work.

Comment: @Raghav Are you have the code in ViewDidLoad or ViewwillAppear ?

Comment: @Vinod, I have used the same code which is there in the answer wrapped in a scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIButton *addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addProject.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18);
[addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(addProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scrollView addSubview:addProject];
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```